# "frame" terminology as used in Veed

Tags: sound-quality, frame-rate

Question is specific to how Veed.io uses the word "Frame". In [its upload link](https://www.veed.io/edit/3b4f87d7-3eab-4139-bbc2-d7ce8f8bbafc?source=%2Ftools%2Faudio-to-text&flow=%7B%22title%22%3A%22Audio+to+Text%22%2C%22flowId%22%3A%22transcribe%22%2C%22steps%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22new-upload%22%2C%22config%22%3A%7B%22noVideo%22%3Afalse%2C%22noAudio%22%3Afalse%2C%22noImage%22%3Atrue%2C%22noTranscript%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22subtitle%22%2C%22config%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22navigation%22%2C%22config%22%3A%7B%22tabHref%22%3A%22%2Fsubtitles%22%2C%22pingTestIds%22%3A%5B%22%40editor%2Fsubtitles%2Fsettings-cog%22%2C%22%40editor%2Fsubtitles%2Fsettings-cog%2Fdownload%22%5D%2C%22pingType%22%3A%22shadow%22%2C%22unselectElement%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%5D%7D)  after uploading there is a settings button at the lower bottom left where you can adjust **Frames Per Second.**

Does changing that setting affect audio/speech quality?

If so, in what ways?

Comment: I'd say a "frame" in video is analogous to a "sample" in audio. Both are the regular and discrete, indivisible temporal steps that make up the whole.

Answer (score 1):

> Does changing that setting affect audio/speech quality?

No. This setting has no association with audio (it doesn't affect it), it is only for setting the resulting video rate.